# What model for a challenging data set? (hundreds of time series with a lot of nesting)

Tags: time-series, mixed-model, repeated-measures, random-effects-model

I have quite a complicated data set to analyze, and I cant find a good solution for it.

Here is the thing:

**1.** the raw data is essentially insect song recordings. Each song is made of several bursts, and each burst made of sub-units. All individuals have been recorded for 5 minutes. The number of bursts and their position in the recording can be very different between individuals, as well as the number of sub-units per burst.

**2.** I have the carrier frequency (fundamental frequency) of each sub-unit, and that's what I want to analyze.

**My problems:**

**1.** The frequencies within a burst are not independent obviously (although it's pretty stable, but the frequency of the sub-unit n-1 will have an influence on the sub-unit n).

**2.** The bursts are also not independent, within a recording.

**3.** They are even less independent as the frequency drops with time (the individual gets tired of singing so the frequency of the song gets lower and lower). The dropping *seems* to be linear.

**4.** Nesting = I have 3 replicated populations for two locations A and B. So I have A1, A2, A3 & B1, B2, B3.

**What I would like to do:**

**1.** Characterize the difference in frequency between my two locations (test it statistically)

**2.** Characterize the frequency dropping between the two locations (see if it drops faster in one of them)

**How to do it:**

Well that's why I need help: I don't know. It seems that my case combines problems that are usually not seen together. I've read about mixed models, about GAM, about ARIMA, random and fixed effects, but I cant be really sure of the best way to do it. 
When I graph it though (frequency ~ sub-unit number *n*), the difference is very clear between the two locations. I also have to take other variables into account, like the temperature (makes the frequency higher), etc.

I thought about:

- Nesting the individuals within the replicate their are from, and nest the replicate within the location (individual/replicate/location).
- Use a random 'burst' effect, so I take into account the variability within each burst.
- Use a fixed 'burst position in recording' effect, to measure the frequency dropping (hoping it is actually linear).

Would it be correct?

Is there a special type of model I could use for this kind of scenario?

Comment: Welcome to this site, Joe. No need to sign in your post, your name will always appear under your gravatar :)

Comment: Ok, and thanks! It's a very nice website, very well-made.

Comment: “Nesting the individuals within the replicate their are from, and nest the replicate within the location (individual/replicate/location)” sounds like a good idea, if compared to the non-nested forms. What does a LOESS of your six sub-populations look like?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers, really appreciated it. Well, it took me a long time, but I managed to analyse this (bloody) dataset. I was too ambitious I think, wanting to model everything at the same time. So I divided in the job in several models, for each problem (average frequency difference, increase in frequency, etc.). Conclusion: sometimes its better to split the job!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just some general suggestions you may find helpful, more a roadmap than a recipe.

- My instinct would be to build a Bayesian hierarchical model, because it lends itself to iterative model development - I don't think you'll find an existing model which has all the bells and whistles you're after. But this makes hypothesis testing harder, I don't know how necessary hypothesis testing is for you.
- It sounds like you've got a little informal model in your head about how the insects behave; you say things like "getting tired" and you know that the temperature makes the frequency higher, presumably because the animal has more energy.  It sounds like you've got a little generative model in your mind about how the insects make their songs.
- The problem sounds way too complex to model "in one shot". I think you'll have to build something up piecemeal. I would start with some "strong simplying assumptions" - i.e., throw away most of the complexity of the dataset, with a plan to add it back in later once you've got a simple model which works.

So to begin, I would do something like preprocess the sub-unit frequencies on a burst-by-burst basis into something like a (mean frequency,frequency trend) pair - do this with OLS, and just model the frequency mean and trend of a burst rather then the sub-units themselves.  Or you could do (mean,trend,# of sub-units), if the number of subunits relates to how tired the insect is getting.  Then build a Bayesian hierarchical model where the distribution of mean and trend of a burst is determined by the mean,trend of the recording, and this in turn is determined by the mean,trend of the location.

Then add temperature in as a factor for the recording mean/trend.

This simple model should allow you to to see the mean and trend of the individual bursts in a recording as determined by the temperature and the location.  Try and get this to work.

Then I would try to estimate the difference between mean frequency of the bursts (or trend, by dividing over the quiet time between bursts) by adding this as a variable determined by the location and recording.  The next step is an AR model of the burst mean within a recording.

Given some priors and some very strong assumptions about the nature of bursts (that all info is given by mean and trend), this basic model will tell you:

- how is the mean frequency of a burst different location by location and temp by temp
- how is the within-burst trend different location by location and temp by temp
- how is the outside-burst trend different location by location and temp by temp

Once you've got something like this to work then it might be time to model the sub-units themselves and throw away the original OLS estimate. I'd look at the data at this point to get an idea of what kind of time-series model might fit, and model the parameters of the time-series model rather than (mean,trend) pairs.